# Debugging typescript with public folder in phpstorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I'm using phpStorm. 
Here is my folder structure

```
/ts - typescript files
/less - less files
/src - php scripts
/node_modules
/public - folder with prepared for production files
    /js - compiled, concated and minified typescript files with gulp
    /css - compiled, concated and minified less files with gulp
    index.php
```

I want to use phpStorm's javascript debugger for debugging typescript files. 
When I set breakepoints in typescripts it's not working which is obvious - browser's js files have nothing to do with ts folder. (http://localhost points to public folder).
How to properly use phpStorm's debugger in such case? Is my folder structure wrong?